# Castalia building error when changing the version of omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I have switched from omnet++5.3 to omnet++4.6. I am using Castalia 3.3.
My installation for the first version of omnet++5.3 was ok with castalia. But when I install the second version and build castalia with it, I have got errors. When I type the command **which opp_makemake** to verify the path, I got **/home/hana/omnet-5.3/bin/opp_makemake** instead of **/home/hana/omnet-6.4/bin/opp_makemake**.

I have changed the path and follow the installation guide for both omnet++ and castalia but still castalia wouldn't run correctly.

Any idea or direction that can help me is appreciated !
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error:

when adding the new path of the new version of installed omnet++4.6 in the .bashrc file, I should delete the older path of the other version of omnet++5.3 (even if it is still installed)

.bashrc doesn't accept two paths for the same software. That works !